# more than 2 values to a key in DICT in Tcl

Tags: tcl

Is it possible to have a dictionary with one key and multiple values to it in TCL

Key - country
value - india, United States, etc?

how?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries have strictly one value per key, but that value can be a list. There's even `dict lappend` to make them easy to build:

```
# Creating
set data {}
dict lappend data country "India"
dict lappend data country "United States"

# Accessing
foreach country [dict get $data country] {
    puts "One country I have is: $country"
}
```

If your data model gets much more complex than that, consider just using an SQLite database. An in-memory database is actually a very good way of replacing most complex data structures (with a far less awful query language!) and going from that to a persistent store is trivial.